# I need help figuring Error bars using python

Tags: python, errorbar

I’m trying to code the equation in figure using Python. The plus/ minus sign refers to some error function and should be indicated using error bars. The plot doesn't look right. Can you please help.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

""" Errors Min and Max """
values1 = []
values2 = []
E1Min  =  []
E1Max  =  []
Eerr = [E1Min, E1Max]

E_error1  = 0.05
E_error2  = 0.04

for E in range(1,1000):       # Energy in GeV

    # Electromagnetic component 99% efficiency. Hadronic component 70% efficiency
    E1 = (0.99 * 0.02 * (1/sqrt(E)) + (0.7 * 0.4 * (1/sqrt(E))))
    values1.append(E1)

    E1_min = (0.99 * (0.02 - E_error1) * (1 / sqrt(E)) + (0.7 * (0.4 - E_error2) * (1 / sqrt(E))))
    E1Min.append(E1_min)
    E1_max = (0.99 * (0.02 + E_error1) * (1 / sqrt(E)) + (0.7 * (0.4 + E_error2) * (1 / sqrt(E))))
    E1Max.append(E1_max)

my_font = 20
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=my_font)
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-", color='0.65')

ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.plot(values1, label=' Not compensated', marker='', color='Blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax1.plot(E1Min, label=' Minimum', marker='', color='Red', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax1.plot(E1Max, label=' Maximum', marker='', color='Red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
ax1.errorbar(values1, E1Max, fmt='o', label=u'Observation Error')
plt.ylabel('Visible Energy [GeV]', fontsize=my_font)
plt.xlabel('Photon energy [GeV]', fontsize=my_font)
plt.title('Visible Energy with/without Compensation', fontsize=my_font)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your equation does not show a square root in the 1/E terms.

Comment: And your equation doesn't have parentheses around the `(0.2 +/- (0.5 * 1/E))`.  Is there supposed to be?  We can't tell if your equation is wrong or your code is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The plot doesn't look right. Can you please help." Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. You need to explain what the error bars actually look like, what they are supposed to look like instead, and (in general terms) what you think is going wrong to cause that difference; then you can ask a *specific* question that indicates *why you actually need help with it*, even after [your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) and debugging efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the parameters to the errorbars function.  The first parameter is the X axis values.  The second parameter is the Y axis values.  The third parameter is the error values.  So:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

E_error1  = 0.05
E_error2  = 0.04

def Efun( E, err1 ):
    return (0.99 * (0.02 + err1) * (1 / np.sqrt(E)) + (0.7 * (0.4 + err2) * (1 / np.sqrt(E))))

E = np.arange(1,1000)
# Electromagnetic component 99% efficiency. Hadronic component 70% efficiency
values1 = Efun( E, 0, 0 )
E1Min = Efun( E, -E_error1, -E_error2 )
E1Max = Efun( E, +E_error1, +E_error2 )

my_font = 20
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=my_font)
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-", color='0.65')

ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.plot(values1, label=' Not compensated', marker='', color='Blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax1.plot(E1Min, label=' Minimum', marker='', color='Red', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
ax1.plot(E1Max, label=' Maximum', marker='', color='Red', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
ax1.errorbar(E, values1, yerr=E1Max-values1, fmt='o', label=u'Observation Error')
plt.ylabel('Visible Energy [GeV]', fontsize=my_font)
plt.xlabel('Photon energy [GeV]', fontsize=my_font)
plt.title('Visible Energy with/without Compensation', fontsize=my_font)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

That looks a lot more like what you expect.

Comment: THANKS Tim, the graph looks way better now. And yes, the square root sign is debatable. I'm checking the notes.